# how to sort date in file php

Tags: sorting, date

I have date in file date.txt in this format

- name:Pol,username:Pol12,date:23 February 2012 11:23:22,password:29d1e2357d7c14db51e885053a58ec67|
- name:Ani,username:Danis,date:23 February 2012 11:26:45,password:29d1e2357d7c14db51e885053a58ec67|
- name:John,username:Johny,date:23 February 2012 12:05:12,password:202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70|

and ect. So I need to sort this records by date and echo this kind info in date.php

- John Johny 23 February 2012 12:05:12
- Ani Danis 23 February 2012 11:26:45
- Pol Pol12 22 February 2012 10:23:22

how can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Read file with [`file()`](http://php.net/file)
2. Split each line by `','`
3. Get rid of name, username, date, etc. (unless you need them, then you could store as array key)
4. use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) to sort by the specified field.

---

```
$file = file('path/to/file');
$lines = array();
foreach($file as $line) {
  $a = array();
  foreach(split(',', $line) as $field) {
    list($key, $val) = split(':', $field, 2);
    $a[$key] = $val;
  }
  $lines[] = $a;
}

usort($lines, function($a, $b) {
  return strtotime($b['date']) - strtotime($a['date']);
});
```

(untested, but should give you an idea)